# DJANGO - Add field to default auth.User model - simplest way

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-2.0

Looking for a simplest way to add one field to `Django's` `User` model.

I have two types of users with different fields - Company and Customer so I decided to create two types of `UserProfiles`. `CompanyProfile` and `CustomerProfile`. Every user has either `CompanyProfile` or `CustomerProfile`.

To be able to `filter` and deciding which type is it, I want to add `type` field to `User` model.

What would you suggest? Now I have `UserProfile` in the middle which seems to be overkill and it makes filtering, lookups and many other things less straightforward.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=settings.OBSTARAJME_USERPROFILE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    company_profile = models.OneToOneField('CompanyProfile', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           related_name='userprofile')
    customer_profile = models.OneToOneField('CustomerProfile', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            related_name='userprofile')
```

I'm considering to create my custom `User` 
model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=settings.OBSTARAJME_USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

but `Django` say's that there is no such field like `username` and I would like to avoid writing whole `User` model and all it's fields manually.

**EDIT**
I know that I could filter based on `customerprofile__isnull=False` so practically, I don't need `type` field at all but it doesn't look to be the best way.

Comment: You should subclass [`AbstractUser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L288), not [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47). The latter only has two fields: password and last_login, while the former is essentially the default `User`, but abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Your last EDIT actually gives away the simplest solution: Don't add a `type` and an intermediate model. What if a `User` at some stage becomes both a `Company` and a `Customer` (even if that's not something you expect now, business requirements change...)? That's not going to be possible with `type`.

So: Just point to `User` using a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField` from your two `Profile` models and don't add anything to `User`.

What you can do to make your code simpler is add a `UserManager` to make your queries more readable:

```
class UserManager(DefaultUserManager):

    def companies(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(customerprofile__isnull=False)
```

that way you can perform queries such as `contract.parties.companies()` (assuming a `contract` has multiple `parties` which are querysets to `User` objects.

With the `UserManager` you also will need to subclass `AbstractUser` to override the default `objects` setting.